# Show matlab figures automatically on the second monitor

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a computer with a second monitor connected under "extended" mode.

When I start my matlab script it will show a figure. In a default mode, the figure always shows on the monitor of my computer. However, instead, I would like for the figure to show directly on the extended monitor. I'd also like for the figure to show with its maximum size.

I searched,  but did not get much luck to find a answer. Anyone here care to enlighten me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I searched and found [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101277-is-it-possible-to-force-matlab-to-bring-up-figure-windows-on-the-primary-monitor-or-in-a-specific-po). Does that help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open a new figure.  Place and resize it where you want on the second monitor.  Then do the following.  Now any new figure should be spawned there.

```
pos = get (gcf, 'position');
set(0, 'DefaultFigurePosition', pos)
```

Note this will only keep for your current matlab session.  So if you want this behavior always you can add it to your [startup.m file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) or create one if you dont have o e already.